# Qual è il significato di "sbarlazzare"?

Tags: word-meaning, verbs

Nella introduzione al *Grammelot dell'avvocato inglese* di *Mistero buffo*, di Dario Fo, ho letto:

> «Ci sono delle fanciulle che incoscienti escono di casa in giornate di gran vento, con lunghi capelli sciolti; vento che **sbarlazza** ogni cosa, specie le loro chiome, che raggiungono quasi il fondo schiena, e che quei refoli turbicanti muovono come bandiere impazzite... e si sa che il capello sbandierato è un richiamo irresistibile per il maschio!»

Ho cercato il verbo "sbarlazzare", ma non l'ho trovato in nessun dizionario. Qualcuno di voi sa cosa significa? Si tratta di un termine di origine dialettale?

Comment: Dal contesto della frase, mi sembra significhi _scompigliare_ o _spazzare_ ma non so dire se sia un termine dialettale

Comment: Nel [vocabolario milanese - italiano di Francesco Cherubini](https://www.google.es/url?q=http://scans.library.utoronto.ca/pdf/4/30/vocabolariomilan00cheruoft/vocabolariomilan00cheruoft.pdf&sa=U&ved=0ahUKEwjsxM3v6NTYAhVH1RQKHct8BhIQFggZMAc&usg=AOvVaw3Nmb7-RzI-3W29ygap_HWG) (1814) appare: «Sbarlà (*e più comunemente* Sbarlass foeura). *Spettorarsi. Sciorinarsi.*»

Comment: Un altro voto negativo senza commento. A proposito, ieri ho posto una domanda sul Meta su questa pratica, che ultimamente mi sembra troppo frequente. Mi piacerebbe conoscere la vostra opinione.

Comment: Giacché non condivido i downvote non giustificati da commento, neutralizzo con un upvote.

Comment: @Charo Ho visto solo ora il tuo commento --- ho messo io questo voto negativo. Il motivo è che queste domande su termini pseudo-dialettali inventati da Dario Fo mi paiono poco utili e interessanti. Ne abbiamo discusse alcune, ma mi sembra che continuare ad averne sempre di nuove non aggiunga molto.

Comment: Grazie del tuo commento, @FedericoPoloni! Forse hai notato che, siccome anch'io ho riflettuto su questo fatto, le mie ultime domande, sebbene sono su termini o espressioni che appaiono su testi di Fo, non sono su vocaboli di probabile origine dialettale (e magari inventati).

Comment: @Charo Ho visto, grazie! Difatti le tue nuove domande non le ho votate negativamente.

Comment: @FedericoPoloni: Tuttavia, come ho già detto in un altro mio commento a un'altra domanda, come straniera, quando non trovo un certo vocabolo nei dizionari, è molto difficile per me essere in grado di capire se si tratta di un'invenzione oppure di italiano regionale. Ho capito però che, se mi trovo in tale situazione in un testo di Fo, devo sospettare che possa essere un termine inventato.